# New shifters for MTB to Gravel Bike (Deore M4120)

Tags: shimano, gears, derailleur

I have a MTB with DEORE RD-M4120 as the rear mech, and am currently running 10 speed, and am looking at converting this into a gravel bike. I want to put drop handlebars onto this new build, and was not sure which ones will work due to the differing pull ratios.

Is anyone able to help with this as I am not sure which shifters will work? Ideally they would be for hydraulic disk compatible aswell.

Many thanks

Comment: This is the use case where Shimano has lagged behind SRAM to an extent that is now weird. Off the shelf SRAM parts can do this easily with hydros, but the only way to do it with Shimano is di2. The closest thing to an exception is using hydraulic STIs plus a pull converter like Jtek, and at that point you're spending a lot just to re-use your current RD.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Microshift SB-M100 will work with your 10 speed Shimano MTB derailleurs.  This is however not for hydraulic brakes.

https://www.microshift.com/models/sb-m100/

Answer (score 0):

Pull ratios started to diverge between road/gravel and MT from 10-speed groupsets.

So unfortunately, no brifter will work.

In 10 speed, it will very hard to find a combination that works with your requirements. In GRX (400), there are only double chainring transmissions, that cannot take cassettes as large as the M4120. And in 1x, it's either 11-speed GRX or Apex (12 and 13 are in other budgets) that take 11/42 cassettes (with hydraulic brakes). Or Microshift Advent X, that take larger cassettes (11/48), but with mechanical gear. So the rear mech wouldn't be the only problem in the conversion.

I also recommend you to have a look on the different questions about flatbar to drop bar conversions.

Comment: I think all the grx derailleurs work on the same pull ratio (cf new tiagra and 11sp) So it could work mechaanically with vaarious combinaations